# Is it possible to connect to SqlServer (MSSQL) with Haskell and Linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux, haskell

It's unclear to me whether anyone has/is successfully connected to MSSQL from Haskell and Linux. I've found things like [this windows guide](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HDBC-ODBC_under_Windows) but nothing promising looking for Linux.
Does anyone have any insight here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [HDBC library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC) lets you connect to any database supporting [ODBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODBC), which I'm quite sure Sql-Server does.

Comment: What SQL server ODBC drivers do you recommend for Linux?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea. My only experience with HDBC-ODBC under Linux is with Oracle drivers. I just happened to remember I'd seen Sql-Server drivers around as well.

Comment: I just can't get this to work. hdbc-odbc + freetds from Ubuntu Haskell. Same issue as this guy 3 years ago: http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/lang-haskell/576857-haskell-unixodbc-freetds.html

Comment: Turns out the TDS_Version is very important to making everything work. Once I set that correctly, ODBC definitely seems like the way to go! Thanks!

Comment: Great to see it worked out! Oracle's ODBC driver for Linux was a pain to get working, but as soon as it was properly deployed, it was smooth sailing from there.